# Tom's mysterious alphanumeric character

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, no-computers

> **Tom:** I drew a mysterious alphanumeric character and showed it to Harry.
>   **Dick**: Harry, was it a letter or a number?
>   **Harry**: I'm not sure!
>   **Dick**: Assuming it was a letter, was it uppercase or lowercase?
>   **Harry**: It could have been either.
>   **Dick**: Assuming it was a number, was it odd or even?
>   **Harry**: Even.

What did Tom draw?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He drew

> a circle.

Explanation

> It could have been either a letter or a number, so it must have been 0/O/o, 1/I/l, or 5/S/s.  Of these, only 0 is even.

Comment: You neglect the possibility of 2/Z/z

Comment: @JeffZeitlin They look very different in my handwriting, but I suppose that's a possibility.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming

> he is not using Roman numerals (already an answer)

He drew a

> 0/o/O or 2/z/Z

all of which look similar if you have no context and based on the person's handwriting and are even

Comment: I would dispute 2 looking like z. I've never seen handwriting where a 2 isn't curved at the top.

Comment: @rybo111 Well, (now you have)[https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ef/EuropeanFormOfArabianDigits.png]. Granted, that's from [1757](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals#Evolution_of_symbols). There are some [fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPNxV.png) that do it, too, but that's not handwriting.

Comment: @EngineerToast If the riddle was written in 1757 or was about fonts I might feel more inclined to accept your point ;)

Comment: @rybo111 my Dad grew up in Germany and he crosses his `Z`s so that they don't look like `2`s. He also crosses his `7`s.

Comment: @EngineerToast for next time, `[text](link)`

Comment: @boboquack Yeah, I get those backwards every now and then.

Answer (score 6):

Well, possible answers are

> O, X, V, I, D, M, C, L

of

> Roman numerals except O !

and based on further answers by Dick, only

> 'O' is eligible to be single alphanumeric character that satisfies the conditions.

Comment: It would appear to me that there are two other possibilities - the one immediately after your choice, and the next-to-last one of your list.

Comment: Given the ambiguity of letter case AND the parity of the numeric value, I would say that three of the value in your list would quality. Jeff Zeitlin is right.

Comment: I agree with @EngineerToast and I think actually 2 and 0 are wrong answers bc 0 is not a circle. and 2 and z look different and It doesn't matter if some people have bad handwriting and write them similarly.

Answer (score 2):

I think he draw

> the cyrillic letter Be: б

It looks like

> number 6

and

> its ascender makes it big enough to pass as uppercase.

Comment: OK, that's a nice non-Latin-alphabet alternative :-)

Comment: Thanks! And based on thegreatemu's answer, there are two other characters from this same alphabet which look like (my "number" - 2). Should I add them?

Comment: Yes, good idea!

Answer (score 1):

I think he drew:

> c/C

Because:

> C in hexadecimal is 12 in decimal. If you drew C without context, it could be interpreted as the letter C or the number C represents. If we assume it is the letter, c/C look the same without other letters for scale. If we assume it is a number, C is even.

Comment: Your ... radical ... suggestion is interesting, but I commend to your attention the cornerstone of a Significant Building.

Answer (score 0):

He drew a

> 'h' or '4' or 'Y'

Because:

> h is a lowercase letter 
>  rotate 180 degrees and you get a capital 'Y' in some handwriting 
>  The same rotation produces a numeral '4'